# Twitter iframe widget remove scrollbar

Tags: jquery, iframe, twitter

Been trying to figure out how to remove the scrollbar in the iframe twitter widget. I know I can't do it with css so my next look was with jquery tried the following but doesn't seem to work

```
$("iframe").ready(function () {
    $(".stream", this).css("overflow-x", "hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to disable it. I used this plug in (https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1) to override twitters css and then just added:

```
.timeline .stream {overflow:hidden;}
```

I also hide the scrollbars by adding the same css directly into a locally stored copy of the twitter widget.js (around line 30).

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution**

Set the scrolling attribute to no in your iframe tag. like this:

```
scrolling="no"
```

Full iframe example:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" title="Twitter Tweet Button" style="border:0;overflow:hidden;" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html"  height="28px" width="76px"></iframe>
```